# Wordpress add Shortcut link to Enable/Disable plugin in admin bar

Tags: wordpress

I would like to add a link to enable and disable a plugin in the admin bar.
Below the code, I wanted to know if it is the correct method.
thank you

```
function custom_admin_bar_link( $admin_bar ) {
    $admin_bar->add_menu( array(
    'id'    => 'wp-custom-link',
    'title' => 'Custom Item',
    'href'  => '',
    'meta'  => array(
             'title' => __('Custom'),
    ),
    ));

    $admin_bar->add_menu( array(
    'id'    => 'disable-link',
    'parent'=> 'wp-custom-link',
    'title' => 'Disable Amazon',
    'href'  => 'https://mydisablelink.com/',
    'meta'  => array(
             'title' => __('Disable Amazon'),
    ),
    ));

    $admin_bar->add_menu( array(
    'id'    => 'unable-link',
    'parent'=> 'wp-custom-link',
    'title' => 'Enable Amazon',
    'href'  => 'https://mydisablelink.com/',
    'meta'  => array(
       'title' => __('Enable Amazon'),
    ),
    ));
}

add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'custom_admin_bar_link', 100 );
```

Comment: Almost. Make sure you check who can see that links, for example, make it visible only for super admin via is_super_admin() function. Also, set your textdomain for strings if you are making the project not only for yourself.

Comment: @Artem   this is the right function      `if ( !is_super_admin() ) {
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'custom_admin_bar_link', 100 );
}`

Comment: `! is_super_admin()` in this case anyone who is not a super admin can see links. Remove `!` to make it work only for the  admin

Comment: @Artem yes you're right ... but it doesn't work, it doesn't show me the link in the admin bar with this code

Comment: @Artem sorry problem was about cache...now show properly